# CSS позиционирование

Tags: css

Как при помощи только css(не редактируя HTML) разместить данные блоки http://jsfiddle.net/runrmtvm/

```html
<div class="img">
  <a href="http://placehold.it/100?text=№1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=№1">
  </a>

</div>
<div class="img">
  <a href="http://placehold.it/100?text=№2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=№2">
  </a>

</div>
<div class="img">
  <a href="http://placehold.it/100?text=№3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=№3">
  </a>

</div>
<div class="img">
  <a href="http://placehold.it/100?text=№4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=№4">
  </a>

</div>
```

так что бы они имели вот такой вод вид:

[image: Пример блоков]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, вот http://jsfiddle.net/vbsLpkup/1/ 
в margin-left подставе проценты какие вам нужно

```
.img:first-child, .img:first-child img{
  width:150px;
  margin:20px auto;
}

.img:not(:first-child){
  float:left;
  margin-left:16%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте nth-child редактировать 
к примеру

```
.img:nth-child(1){
width:150px; 
margin:auto;//или позиционированием
}
.img:nth-child(2){
margin-left:150px;
float:left;}
.img:nth-child(3){
margin-left:100px;
float:left;}
.img:nth-child(4){
margin-left:100px;
float:left;}
```

Comment: не совсем так, нижние блоки не по центру а зависимые от `margin-left`

Comment: проблема в css что все блоки позицианируются не по центру а от левого края экрана иначе бы небыло 100500 рецептов как что от позициаонировать.
Попробуйте следующий рецепт второй ряд пишите так первый элемент
position:absolute;left:25%;margin-left:-(половина размера выравниваемого блока);
второй 
position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-(половина размера выравниваемого блока);
третий 
position:absolute;left:75%;margin-left:-(половина размера выравниваемого блока);

Comment: так я и прошу рецепт, иначе бы не писал тут.

Comment: проверте ещё раз верхний коментарий

Comment: то что нужно,
http://jsfiddle.net/runrmtvm/3/

Comment: ну поиграйтесь с процентами в left.